# how to put condition alert box in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

can anyone help me...how do i put an conditional alert dialog box in ajax that if the data in a query is successfully saved or the data already been saved.

I want to do is if the query is saved an alert box will pop-op same goes to if the data is already been saved.

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#updates').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data.region_text = $('#t_region').val();
        data.town_text = $('#t_town').val();
        data.uniq_id_text = $('#t_uniq_id').val();
        data.position_text = $('#t_position').val();
        data.salary_grade_text = $('#t_salary_grade').val();
        data.salary_text = $('#t_salary').val();

        for(var $x=1;$x<=15;$x++) {
            data['id'+$x+'_text'] = $('#id'+$x).val();
            data['aic'+$x+'_text'] = $('#aic'+$x).val();
            data['name'+$x+'_text'] = $('#name'+$x).val();
            data['optA'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optA'+$x).val();
            data['optB'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optB'+$x).val();
            data['optC'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optC'+$x).val();
            data['optD'+$x+'_text'] = $('#optD'+$x).val();
            data['other_qual'+$x+'_text'] = $('#other_qual'+$x).val();
            data['interview'+$x+'_text'] = $('#interview'+$x).val();
            data['total'+$x+'_text'] = $('#total'+$x).val();
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
            // We are using response to distinguish our outer data variable here from the response
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

insert.php code:

```
<?php
    include('../connection.php');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');  

    $region        = @$_POST['region_text'];
    $town          = @$_POST['town_text'];
    $uniq_id       = @$_POST['uniq_id_text'];
    $position      = @$_POST['position_text'];
    $salary_grade  = @$_POST['salary_grade_text'];
    $salary        = @$_POST['salary_text'];

$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM afnup_worksheet WHERE funiq_id = '$uniq_id'";
$duperow = mysql_query($dupesql);
if(mysql_num_rows($duperow) > 0){
    exit;
}else{

    for($n=1;$n<=15;$n++)   {


    $id           = @$_POST['id'.$n.'_text'];
    $aic          = @$_POST['aic'.$n.'_text'];
    $name         = @$_POST['name'.$n.'_text'];
    $optA         = @$_POST['optA'.$n.'_text'];
    $optB         = @$_POST['optB'.$n.'_text'];
    $optC         = @$_POST['optC'.$n.'_text'];
    $optD         = @$_POST['optD'.$n.'_text'];
    $other_qual   = @$_POST['other_qual'.$n.'_text'];
    $interview    = @$_POST['interview'.$n.'_text'];
    $total        = @$_POST['total'.$n.'_text'];



if(!empty($name)){
$query = "INSERT INTO afnup_worksheet (faic,fregion,ftown,funiq_id,fposition,fsalary_grade,fsalary,fnl_name,edu_attain,experience,seminars,eligibility,other_qual,interview,ftotal,dateinputed) 
VALUES 
('$aic','$region','$town','$uniq_id','$position','$salary_grade','$salary','$name','$optA','$optB','$optC','$optD','$other_qual','$interview','$total',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$resource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return that status from PHP:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($duperow) > 0){
    echo "1"; // Dup status
    exit;
}else{
    // All your else code.. echo must be the last thing inside your else block
    echo "2"; // Saved status
}
```

Then in your ajax `success` callback you check it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (response) {
        if (Number(response) == 1)
        {
            alert("Dup message");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Saved message");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exit; in your conditinal for dupes, you could echo "duplicate". Also you should remove die() after your $resource and add if ($resource) echo "ok"; else echo "error";

Then in your success function(response) in javascript you can do if (response=="...") echo duplicate; else if ...

This is just basic explanation, but it should be enough to point you in the right direction.